# Displaying name of point with shapely

Tags: python, shapely, point-in-polygon, display, propertyname

I want to display the names of points on my polygon with shapely.

```
Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)])
```

and

```
Names = [A, B, C, D, A]
```

How can I do it simply?

Answer (score 1):

Shapely is about geometry and geometry only but you can do it indirectly

```
pol = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]) 
# extract the points
pts = list(pol.exterior.coords)
Names=["A","B","C","D","A"]
list(zip(Names,pts))
[('A', (0.0, 0.0)), ('B', (0.0, 2.0)), ('C', (2.0, 2.0)), ('D', (2.0, 0.0)), ('A', (0.0, 0.0))]
dict(zip(Names, pts))
{'A': (0.0, 0.0), 'B': (0.0, 2.0), 'C': (2.0, 2.0), 'D': (2.0, 0.0)}
or
pts = [Point(i) for i in pts]
list(zip(Names,pts))
('A', <POINT (0 0)>), ('B', <POINT (0 2)>), ('C', <POINT (2 2)>), ('D', <POINT (2 0)>), ('A', <POINT (0 0)>)]
dict(zip(Names,pts))
{'A': <POINT (0 0)>, 'B': <POINT (0 2)>, 'C': <POINT (2 2)>, 'D': <POINT (2 0)>}
```

You need to plot the polygon and the points

[image]